# Wrap this custom field with hyperlink link

Tags: custom-field

Just created a custom field from scratch by following a tutorial. I have a field for a website link. Currently it outputs only raw text, no linking.

So how do I make this code hyperlink:

```
<li><strong>Website:</strong> '.$_imd_portfolio_website_output.'</li>
```

Full code:

```
function imd_portfolio_meta_box() {
    global $post;
    // get the custom field values as an array
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    // extract the members of the $values array to their own variables (which you can see below, in the HTML code)
    extract( $values, EXTR_SKIP );

    // escape the output, just in case
    $allowed_html = array(
        'a' => array(
            'href' => array(),
            'title' => array()
        ),
        'em' => array(),
        'strong' => array()
    );
    $_imd_portfolio_details_output = wp_kses($_imd_portfolio_details[0], $allowed_html);
    $_imd_portfolio_client_output = wp_kses($_imd_portfolio_client[0], $allowed_html);
    $_imd_portfolio_website_output = wp_kses($_imd_portfolio_website[0], $allowed_html);
    $_imd_portfolio_quote_output = wp_kses($_imd_portfolio_quote[0], $allowed_html);
    $output = '<div class="review-box">
        <ul class="review-box-list">
            <li><strong>Details:</strong> '.$_imd_portfolio_details_output.'</li>
            <li><strong>Client:</strong> '.$_imd_portfolio_client_output.'</li>
            <li><strong>Website:</strong> '.$_imd_portfolio_website_output.'</li>
            <li><strong>Quote:</strong>'.$_imd_portfolio_quote_output.'></li>
        </ul>
    </div>';
    return $output;
}
```

Update:
the problem is solved
I've edit my code & change this line -

```
<li><strong>Website:</strong> '.$_imd_portfolio_website_output.'</li>
```

to this line-

```
<li><strong>Website:</strong><a href="http://'.$_imd_portfolio_website_output.'">'.$_imd_portfolio_website_output.'</a></li>
```

thanks everybody for help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by validating and wrapping a anchor tag. First check that in the input, which user has given any has prefix like `http://` or `www` or not. If user has not given that then add the prefix with the input and place it at the `href` attribute of the anchor tag. I think it will do the work

Comment: can you tell me, where should I change my codes with adding the prefix? I'm still in the learning stage of PHP. here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/kyjAs8Ba

Comment: @user2802110 Please add your code as an edit to your question ^^